# React Native: make API request, set State, and THEN render?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, async-await

Sorry if this is obvious somewhere in the documentation, but I am trying to wait until my state is set on a parent component before rendering a child component:

Paraphrasing:

```
class Parent extends Component {

  componentWillMount() {
    firestack.database.ref()
      .then((snapshot) => {
        this.setState({myVal: snapshot.val})
      })
  }

  render() {
    // Renders before request finishes setting state,
    // Child component receives an undefined val
    return (
      <ChildComponent
        myVal={this.state.myVal}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

My render hits before the request finishes, so I'm not able to pass the new State to the child component's constructor. How can I properly do this?
Hopefully this is low hanging fruit to someone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I recommend moving your async request to `componentDidMount`. Not mandatory, but it's a better point in the life-cycle. Your component will need to able to handle `myVal == undefined` anyway.

Then, don't render the child component until `myVal` is available:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      { this.state.myVal && <ChildComponent myVal={this.state.myVal} /> }
    </div>
  )
}
```

Or perhaps, render a spinner instead:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      { this.state.myVal 
        ? <ChildComponent myVal={this.state.myVal} />
        : <Spinner />
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

Note:

- You can't use `if` inside JSX, so this not-so-kosher use of `&&` is required to keep the syntax compact. A common pattern.
- You can have a `this.state.isReady` boolean instead of asking for the presence of a specific value. Another common pattern.
- If `ChildComponent` is the only element you're going to render, you may not need the `<div />` wrapper, but you usually do for some reason or other.

Comment: `this.state.myVal && ` construction has two subtles. At first, it's ignoring `0` or other falsy non-undefined value. Also it outputs `0` for `0` value

Answer (score 2):

If the `myVal` parameter is a required for `ChildComponent`, you just need to do this in parent:

```
return (
  {this.state.myVal !== undefined &&
    <ChildComponent
      myVal={this.state.myVal}
    />
  }
)
```

Then react will render empty string at first time and after changing state it will render again with filled `myVal` value.

Also, as it was mentioned in another answer, it's much better to use `componentDidMount`.

Answer (score 0):

It's recommend to do your API calls within `componentDidMount` rather than `componentWillMount`. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount

> Setting state in this method will trigger a re-rendering.

Comment: Yes, except, this does not set state in my child component, since the constructor of the child component is only hit once initially.

Comment: You can set a default State within the `constructor`, check for the value's initialisation in your Parent's render method (like @lunochkin's suggestion) or check for the value's initialisation in your Child's render method.